# How prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\pi{(n)}}{n^2}<\infty$ for some bijective $\pi(n)$

Tags: analysis

Let $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,\cdots\}$.  Does there exist a bijective function $\pi:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\pi{(n)}}{n^2}<\infty ?$$

My try: note
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^2} $$ is convergent,

and then I can't. Thank you.